# Javascript select onchange not fired properly

Tags: javascript, html

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="selection" value="wifi" checked onclick="filterLog(this)">wifi</label><br>
<select id="wifi" class="dropdownList" multiple size=3 onchange="filterLogSel()">



    function filterLogSel() {
        /* not fired by checkbox */
        if (!checkMark) {
            var breakCheck;
            /* remove all the content */
            var htmlSelectAdd = document.getElementById('logListBox');
            for(var i=0, n=htmlSelectAdd.length; i<n; i++) {
                htmlSelectAdd.options[i].remove();
                n--;
                i--;
            }
            /* add content according to the select value */
            selecttags = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdownList');
            for (key in jsonobj)
                for(var i=0, n=selecttags.length; i<n; i++) {
                    for(var j=0, m=selecttags[i].length; j<m; j++) {
                        if (selecttags[i].options[j].selected) {
                            var re=new RegExp(selecttags[i].options[j].value);
                            if ((re.exec(jsonobj[key]))!=null) {
                                selectBoxOption = document.createElement("option");
                                selectBoxOption.value = key;
                                selectBoxOption.text = jsonobj[key];
                                htmlSelectAdd.add(selectBoxOption,null);
                                breakCheck = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (breakCheck) {
                        breakCheck = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

When I debug this in chrome, I find that when I click the options in a select tag it will fire checkbox's onclick function instead of select's onchange function. I want the select's onchange function fired.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're seeing this is that your dropdown is a multiple select drop down.  If you change your drop down to only be one option then it will fire the onchange event.  Since you're actually clicking when it's multi-select it's correct that the onclick() event be fired.

Comment: Is there any solution that keeps the multiple attribute and fire the onchange function?

Comment: Nope you can basically have one or the other.